# Manipulating objects in array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have this javascript objects:

```
var arr1 = [{id:'124',name:'qqq'}, 
           {id:'589',name:'www'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'eee'},
           {id:'567',name:'rrr'}]

var arr2 = [{id:'124',name:'ttt'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'yyy'}
```

I need to replace objects in arr1 with items from arr2 with same id.

Here how I achive the desired result:

```
arr1.map(obj => arr2.find(o => o.id === obj.id) || obj);
```

And here is the result:

```
var arr1 = [{id:'124',name:'ttt'}, 
           {id:'589',name:'em'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'yyy'},
           {id:'567',name:'eme'}];
```

But the problem that this solution:

```
arr1.map(obj => arr2.find(o => o.id === obj.id) || obj);
```

Don't work in IE browser.

How can I change the row above to get the desired result in IE and chrome browsers?

```js
var arr1 = [{
    id: '124',
    name: 'qqq'
}, {
    id: '589',
    name: 'www'
}, {
    id: '45',
    name: 'eee'
}, {
    id: '567',
    name: 'rrr'
}];

var arr2 = [{
    id: '124',
    name: 'ttt'
}, {
    id: '45',
    name: 'yyy'
}];

var res = arr1.map(obj => arr2.find(o => o.id === obj.id) || obj);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: What version of IE? You are using `find` and arrow functions which are ES6 features...

Comment: You could use a loop!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Array.prototype.find()` you would need to use recommended polyfill for browsers that don't support it.

See [MDN Array.protoype.find() polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a polyfill, simply reduce the ids first then map.

```
var arr1 = [{id:'124',name:'qqq'}, 
           {id:'589',name:'www'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'eee'},
           {id:'567',name:'rrr'}]

var arr2 = [{id:'124',name:'ttt'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'yyy'}]

var byIds = arr2.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item.id] = item;
    return acc;
}, {})

var replacedArr1 = arr1.map(item => byIds[item.id] || item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged `lodash` to this, so why not use lodash functions [_ .find](https://lodash.com/docs#find) and [_ .map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) instead of the native functions with limited browser support.

```
_.map(arr1, obj => _.find(arr2, o => o.id === obj.id) || obj);
```

To state the obvious, you also need to transpile the ES6 style arrow functions and what not to support older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over `arr2` and build an object as hash table and then iterate over `arr1` for changing the elements.

```js
var arr1 = [{ id: '124', name: 'qqq' }, { id: '589', name: 'www' }, { id: '45', name: 'eee' }, { id: '567', name: 'rrr' }],
    arr2 = [{ id: '124', name: 'ttt' }, { id: '45', name: 'yyy' }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

arr2.forEach(function (a) {
    this[a.id] = a;
}, hash);

arr1.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    if (this[a.id]) {
        aa[i] = this[a.id];
    }
}, hash);

console.log(arr1);
```

Or use a version with short circuit.

```js
var arr1 = [{ id: '124', name: 'qqq' }, { id: '589', name: 'www' }, { id: '45', name: 'eee' }, { id: '567', name: 'rrr' }],
    arr2 = [{ id: '124', name: 'ttt' }, { id: '45', name: 'yyy' }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

hash.count = arr2.length;

arr2.forEach(function (a) {
    this[a.id] = a;
}, hash);

arr1.some(function (a, i, aa) {
    if (this[a.id]) {
        aa[i] = this[a.id];
        return !--this.count;
    }
}, hash);

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use a for loop to loop through each item in the 2nd array. Then loop through the first array to see if the ID matches. If it does, set the name to the name from the second array.

```
var arr1 = [{id:'124',name:'qqq'}, 
       {id:'589',name:'www'}, 
       {id:'45',name:'eee'},
       {id:'567',name:'rrr'}];

var arr2 = [{id:'124',name:'ttt'}, 
       {id:'45',name:'yyy'}];

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
        if (arr2[i].id === arr1[j].id) {
            arr1[j].name = arr2[i].name;
        }
    }   
}
```

here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k0grurx5/

Answer (score 0):

Please, did you think of [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) you will find cross browser functions like `find`, `filter` and `map`

```
 int lastIndex = 0 
 var result = _.map(arr1 , function(num){ 
      if (arr1.id == arr2[lastIndex].id){
         return arr2[lastIndex++];
      }
      return arr1;
 });
```